# Is there a way to listen to route change in current route and cancel it if needed

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a function that ask the user if he finished completing his profile before changing route.

For example:

```
-> User complete his profile 
-> He press on a button that navigate to other route 
-> There is a dialog that ask if he wants to continue 
-> He press "no" 
-> The navigation is canceled
```

So I need to implement the "navigation is canceled" part, but how ?

I could do this by showing the dialog before every call to the Navigator but in my case I'm using a Navbar that includes every buttons that changes the route, so I can't edit the functions.

What I want is like a listener :

```
beforeDispose() {
  bool continue = false;
  if (!continue) {
    cancelDispose() or cancelRouting()
}
}
```

Maybe there is a way with the `onDispose()` function, but I don't know how

Comment: the step #2 and step #3 should be swapped, so it looks:  "There is a dialog that ask if he wants to continue " followed by "He press on a button that navigate to other route "

Comment: The thing is that I'm using a button (navbar) that I use on lots of routes so I can't do this. What I want is like a listener, I edited my main post to show you an example